# Adding a ScrollPager Tool to a TeeChart shrinks the whole chart

Tags: c#, wpf, teechart

I am trying to add a scroll pager to a tchart like in the example code (but for WPF) and I get a very strange result

Before I add a scroll pager.
[image]

After
[image]

```
Chart.Series.Clear();
Chart.Header.Text = "Plot";
Chart.Axes.Automatic = true;
Chart.Legend.TopLeftPos = 0;
Chart.Axes.Bottom.Labels.DateTimeFormat = "HH:mm:ss";
Chart.Axes.Bottom.Labels.LabelsAsLocalTime = true;
Chart.Legend.LegendStyle = Steema.TeeChart.WPF.LegendStyles.Series;

FastLine series = new FastLine();
Chart.Series.Add(series);
series.FillSampleValues(1000);
Chart.Tools.Add(_scrollPager = new ScrollPager());
Chart.Tools.Add(_nearestPoint = new NearestPoint());
Chart.Tools.Add(_annotate = new Annotation());

_scrollPager.Series = series;

_nearestPoint.Series = series;
_nearestPoint.Brush.Color = _scrollPager.PointerHighlightColor;
_nearestPoint.DrawLine = false;
_nearestPoint.Size = 6;
_nearestPoint.Direction = NearestPointDirection.Horizontal;

_annotate.Position = AnnotationPositions.RightTop;
_annotate.Text = "YValue:";
_annotate.Shape.Shadow.Visible = false;
_annotate.Shape.Font.Color = Chart.Header.Font.Color;
_annotate.Shape.Color = _scrollPager.PointerHighlightColor;
_annotate.Shape.Pen.Visible = false;
_annotate.TextAlign = TextAlignment.Center;
```

Any ideas would be gratefully received!

Comment: Full code sample is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/voghqgxfbo5hup4/ScrollPagerTest.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

We could reproduce the problem so we added it to the public tracker:
http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=1672

Note we have a fix in the works.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't know were the ticket came from